# group_concat in mysql query stops early

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with group_concat in mysql query :

It stops on 513 number !

This is the normal query  and it returns 813 rows :

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey_votes
WHERE sid =  '4'
```

and now the problem is with this query:

```
SELECT s.*,     
    GROUP_CONCAT(v.oid) AS myoids
    FROM survey s
    LEFT JOIN survey_votes v ON s.sid=v.sid
    WHERE s.sid='4'
```

This returns 1 row containing an array 'myoids' up to 513 strings.

strucutr of table 'survey':

```
sid  int(11)          
stitle   varchar(255)
sdesc    text     
soptions text    
sdate    datetime  
active   int(1)
```

survey_votes:

```
vid int(11) 
sid int(11)     
uid int(11)     
uip varchar(255)    
oid int(11)     
sdate   datetime
```

***myoids*** only contains upto 513 rows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
    .........
    [511] => 1
    [512] => 
)
```

Comment: Interesting. Is your type in the question on purpose? Correcting it to problem is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because MySQL truncates the result of [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) after a certain limit:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024.

Try increasing the value of [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) variable using the `SET` command:

```sql
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024; -- 1MB
```

Comment: YEAH , This is the correct answer !  Now how can I solve it and increase it?

Comment: SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = 2048 !

Comment: But still sticks with 513 ! should I restart mysql service ?

Comment: Can you check the result of the query `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 2048; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len';`?

Comment: group_concat_max_len  2048

Answer (score 0):

the query should be

```
SELECT s.*,     
GROUP_CONCAT(v.oid) AS myoids
FROM survey s
LEFT JOIN survey_votes v ON s.sid=v.sid
WHERE v.sid='4'
      // here was the problem it should be v.sid not s.sid
```

Because in your first query you are selecting from `survey_votes` where `sid =  '4'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey_votes
WHERE sid =  '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does this return:

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey
WHERE sid =  '4'
```

Does this return 513 rows?