# Why does my SQL script stops?

Tags: php, mysql, function, size, prestashop

I have a question regarding PHP/MYSQL. I have a function which gets a list of colors in a MYSQL table and renders them into numerous HTML tables. Idea is that most of the will be hidden unless the customer chooses a certain option. When the user puts his mouse over a color it loads a more detailed picture. It works fine, however after a certain number of caracters the script stops executing, here is the code:

Request:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(description ORDER BY i.model_correspondance ASC) AS concat,     GROUP_CONCAT(model_correspondance ORDER BY i.model_correspondance ASC) AS modell, GROUP_CONCAT(element) AS elem, GROUP_CONCAT(coordinates ORDER BY i.model_correspondance ASC) AS coord FROM design_tool_items AS i WHERE i.model='.$shoe.' GROUP BY i.element, i.category, i.subelement ORDER BY i.id ASC';
```

And the rest of the PHP:

```
        if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)) {
            foreach ($results as $row) {

                if($row['subelement']=='') {
                    if(isset($i)) $code .= '</div>';
                        $code .= '<div class="'.$display.' color_holder" rel="'.$row['style'].'" id="div'.$row['subelement'].'.'.$row['element'].'">';
                        $i=1;
                } else {
                    $code .= '</div>';
                    $code .= '<div class="no color_holder" rel="'.$row['style'].'" id="div'.$row['subelement'].'.'.$row['element'].'">';
                }

                $sentinel = $row['element'];
                $code .= '<div style="text-align:left;padding:10px">'.$row['category'].'</div>';
                $concat = explode(',', $row['concat']);
                $coordinate = explode(',', $row['coord']);
                $model_corres = explode(',', $row['modell']);

                foreach($concat as $item => $corres) {

                    if(($i==1)&&(array_search($sentinel, $array_elements)===false)) { 
                        $array_elements[] = $sentinel;
                        $select = 'selected';
                    } else $select = '';

                    $coord = explode('#', $coordinate[$item]);

                    $clean_array = array($row['category'], $corres);
                    foreach($clean_array as &$text) {
                        $text = str_replace(' ', '_', $text);
                        $text = strtolower($text);  
                    }

                    $code .= '<div style="width:60px;padding-left:10px;margin:auto;float:left;">';
                    $code .= '<div onmouseover="Tip(\'<div><img style=width:200px;height:200px; src='.$val.'folded_images/'.$clean_array[0].'/'.$clean_array[1].'.jpg alt=Image:'.$corres.' /><br>'.$corres.'</div>\')" onmouseout="UnTip()" rel="'.$row['style'].'" denom="'.$row['subelement'].'.'.$sentinel.$model_corres[$item].'" class="color '.$select.'" style="background-position:'.$coord[0].'px '.$coord[1].'px;"></div>';
                    $code .= '</div>';
                    if(is_int($i/3)) $code .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
                    $i++;
                }
                $code .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            }
        }

        return $code;
```

At the 100th line the script stops working in the middle and shows only the first three characters of the description. If I reduce the length of the previous descriptions it works further so the problem comes from the array $concat.

Do you think there is a size limit (I know about the 128Mb in PHP 5.2 and 8Mb before however the website runs PHP 5.2.3 and I think I am far from 128Mb)?

Sorry about the long topic, thank you in advance to everyone who will put attention on this.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the use of `GROUP_CONCAT`.

A helpfull link that might be useful. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702177/group-concat-in-mysql-query-stops-early)

Comment: ur welcome. if you thinks it answer your problem you can accept it as answer

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes first, but yes will do

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to [max execution time](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set) and/or [memory limit](http://www.hostucan.com/webmaster-tutorials/increase-php-memory-limit). Worth tweaking each separately (and then, if in doubt, together) and see if you get favorable results. You may also want to enable better [debug logging for PHP](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php).